# Changing datapoint trailing decimals in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

Is there a param setting that allows me to format the trailing decimals for the actual data point and not the axis tick?

For example, if I pass the following point:

`[1, 50.5]`

flot outputs this (with hovering enabled) as 50.50.  I have tried to change that tickSize and tickDecimals as can be seen below:

`{tickSize:1, tickDecimals:1}`

but this only formats the tick and not the actual datapoint.  Is there a param setting that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can!  The [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) is the place to look for this, and they even give the exact thing you need in there.

```
function formatter(val, axis) {
  return val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals);
}
```

So when you are defining your options you need to add that in there like so:

```
{ 
  ...,
  xaxis: {
      ....,
      tickFormatter: function(val,axis){
         return val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals);
      }
}
```